# How to pass value from django templated html to ajax

Tags: html, ajax, django, django-templates

I have been hacking away at this for too long, as I'm painstakingly introducing ajax to speed my django app. I have no prior experience so. I have a dropdown list that I'm using as a notification viewer and using the {%for loop%} to populate. They all share the same id but unique names - their record ids. I'm trying to click the notification and then load the corresponding records by passing's it's ID to my views.py file. Below is code for my hackish attempt which has failed to be fruitful and taken way to much time.

```
<script>
    function openNotification(){
        $('#ntfy').click(function(e) {
            var acc = $(this).attr('name');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{% url 'my_app:notifications' %}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                data:{csrfmiddlewaretoken :'{{ csrf_token }}',
                     'acc':acc},
                success: function(){
                    alert("yo yoyo");
                    if (data.status == "success"){
                        window.location.href = data.url;
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("error occured");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

And the html looks like this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="openNotification()" name="{{alert.1.docnum}}_{{alert.0.accountid}}" id="#ntfy">
```

Please assist.

Comment: what is `acc` ? are you trying to access value as `{{alert.1.docnum}}` and `{{alert.0.accountid}}` ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've edited to show what I intended. I'm hoping to pass those 2 as one value as the notification is a composite primary key

Comment: Understood, check my answer of 2 different methods. Should work.

Comment: callback function was missing `data` variable, so I added that now please you fix that too.

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm. Opted for the second version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="#" data-docnum="{{alert.1.docnum}}" data-accountid="{{alert.0.accountid}}" class="ntfy">
```

===========================================

```
<script>
    $('.ntfy').on('click',function(e) {
        var docnum = $(this).attr('data-docnum'); // or $(this).data('docnum')
        var accountid = $(this).attr('data-accountid'); // or $(this).data('accountid')
        data = {
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken":$("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
            "docnum":docnum,
            "accountid":accountid
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'rznbldbt_app:notifications' %}",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            data:data,
            success: function(data){
                alert("yo yoyo");
                if (data.status == "success"){
                    window.location.href = data.url;
                }
                else{
                    alert("error occured");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Another way is :

```
<a href="#" onclick="openNotification({{alert.1.docnum}},{{alert.0.accountid}});">
```

===========================================

```
<script>    
    function openNotification(docnum,accountid)
    {
        data = {
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken":$("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
            "docnum":docnum,
            "accountid":accountid
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'rznbldbt_app:notifications' %}",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            data:data,
            success: function(data){
                alert("yo yoyo");
                if (data.status == "success"){
                    window.location.href = data.url;
                }
                else{
                    alert("error occured");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```